# Dynamic OrderBy fails for nullable column

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, nullable

There is a table `Customers` with a nullable `cstCredit` column. The following works fine and can be iterated.

```
var query = _oContext.Customers.OrderBy(cst => cst.cstCredit);
```

However, the following will fail when iterating.

```
public IQueryable<Customer> AllSorted(Expression<Func<Customer, object>> orderby)
{
   return _oContext.Customers.OrderBy(orderby);
}

void test()
{
   var query = AllSorted(cst => cst.cstCredit);
   foreach (Customer oCustomer in query)
   {
   }
}
```

The message (translated from German) is

> "The type System.Nullable can not be converted to System.Object. LINQ
>   to Entities only supports converting primitive or enumeration types".

What have I done wrong?

Comment: What's the type of `cstCredit`? You say `object` (inside `Expression<Func<Customer, object>>`).

Comment: possibly add a `.where` before the `.orderby` and check for `cst.cstCredit != null`?

Comment: is `cstCredit` nullable?

Comment: @TravisJ based on the question it appears so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing the `AllSorted` method like this:

```
public IQueryable<Customer> AllSorted<TKey>(Expression<Func<Customer, TKey>> orderby)
{
   return _oContext.Customers.OrderBy(orderby);
}
```

It didn't work because nullable types like `int?` are value types are do not derive from object ( and are instances of the `System.Nullable` struct) and hence `Expression<Func<Customer, object>> orderby` would not work with them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public IQueryable<Customer> AllSorted<T>(Expression<Func<Customer, T>> orderby)
{
   return _oContext.Customers.OrderBy(orderby);
}
```